# Multidimensional Array Function not behaving as expected in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array

I am trying to understand why my code does not function as expected. This code I am running in a snippet in the browser:

```
    function generateMaze(n) {
      //   let n = document.getElementById("maze-size").value;
      let maze = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let mazeWidth = new Array(n)
          .fill(1)
          .map((x) => (Math.random() >= 0.3 ? 1 : 0));
        maze.push(mazeWidth);
      }
      console.log(maze);
    }
    
    console.log(generateMaze(5))
```

In the webpage I have the html: The only thing that differs here is that there is these 2 lines above the function to get the value and pass it to the function. I will include the full index.js at the end

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="maze-size">Input desired Maze Size</label>
          <input id="maze-size" name="mazesize" type="text" />
          <button id="generateMaze">
            <p id="mazearea"></p>
            Generate
          </button>
        </div>
      </body>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
    </html>
```

index.js

```
    "use strict";
    
    const button = document.getElementById("generateMaze");
    
    button.addEventListener("click", generateMaze);
    
    function generateMaze() {
      let n = document.getElementById("maze-size").value;
      let maze = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let mazeWidth = new Array(n)
          .fill(1)
          .map((x) => (Math.random() >= 0.3 ? 1 : 0));
        maze.push(mazeWidth);
      }
    }
```

Summary is:
This works perfectly as a standalone function generating a matrix 2d array with the defined input:

eg:

```
[
   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
]
```

but when I use this function attached to a button I get an output of only 1 element in n number of arrays and I do not understand why.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: `n` is a string in your second example, as that's what `.value` returns when you use it on an element object, so if `n = "4"` for example and you use `new Array(n)` (which is `new Array("4")` in this example) you'll get `["4"]`. If `n` is a number, eg: `new Arrray(4)`, then you'll get an array of length `4` as expected

Comment: `n` is string, you need to convert it to number.

Comment: Thank you both! It was a small oversight but immediately fixed my problem. Thank you.